# htaccess query_string

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Search engines crawl the site with parameters

```
/?p=([0-9]+)
/?cat=([0-9]+)
/?do=([a-z]+)
```

etc

How make in .htaccess to inform the search engines that such pages no longer exists?

I have only /?page=([0-9]+)

Thanks.

I tried

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(p|cat|do)(.*)$
RewriteRule ^$ http://test.com/simple [R=301,L]
```

but

```
http://test.com/?p=23 give me http://test.com/test?p=23 (not http://test.com/test)
http://test.com/?cat=11 give me http://test.com/test?cat=11 (not http://test.com/test)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest following 301 (Permanent Redirect) rule for you:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^page=.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://test.com/test? [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect every `/?p=([0-9]+)` or `/?do=([0-9]+)` or `/?foo=([0-9]+)` or `/?bar=([0-9]+)` etc (any query string except `/?page=`) to `http://test.com/test` with `R=301` and remove the original query string (notice `?` in the end of target URL).

Answer (score 0):

You could add those pages to your [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org) file to prevent the indexing.

However, somewhere the search engines are *finding* these links. You should ensure that you are not using them on your site.

If the pages *no longer exist*, you might consider [redirecting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) (301) them accordingly.

The latter, or some combination therein should sort you out.

Comment: robots.txt only for search engines, I need this to work also for users.

Comment: I already did it. Not as I would like, but it works.  `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(p\=|cat\=|do\=|feed\=|tag\=|m\=|paged\=)(.*)$  RewriteRule ^$ http://www.test.com/\? [R=301,L]`